# Prevent Titanium webview scrolling altogether?

Tags: uiwebview, titanium

I have a small webview in my Titanium/iOS app with an HTML select element. When the user makes a selection, the webview scrolls. How can I prevent the webview from scrolling?

```
var html = '<html>';
html += '<head>';
html += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>';
html += '<script src="lib/attributeForm.js"></script>';
html += '<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>';
html += '<script src="jq/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>';
html += '</head>';
html += '<body style="overflow: hidden">';
html += '<form style="margin:10px; min-height:500px;" id="attributeForm">'+win.attributeForm+'<br><br><br><br></form>';
html += '</body>';
html += '</html>';

var webview = createWebView({
    top: y,
    height: 250,
    html: html,
    disableBounce: true,
});
```

And here is the attributeForm.js:

```
function getAttributes() {
    return $('#attributeForm').serialize();
}

document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    // This prevents native scrolling from happening.
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by preventing the touchmove event, via JavaScript in the Web View:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    // This prevents native scrolling from happening.
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

You can see the full sample here: https://gist.github.com/819929

Comment: This didn't change the scroll happening in my webview - please see this code added to the js file above.

Answer (score 2):

Though a bit later, but should be effective who will face the same problem. Try..
`disableBounce : true` inside your **webview** property.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably in your HTML rather than in the app code...not seeing any code it's hard to say, but you can try setting `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` of your webview HTML.

Comment: This didn't stop the scroll. My scrolling must be in the interface created by Titanium.